# How can place a job of linux terminal to background after enter password?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I use this command in linux terminal to connect to a server and use it as proxy :

```
ssh -N -D 7070 root@ip_address
```

it's get the password and connect and everything is Ok but how can I put this process in background ?

I used CTRL+Z but it stop not put this process in background ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTRL-Z is doing exactly what it should, which is stop the process. If you then want to put it in the background, the shell command for doing that is `bg`:

```
$ ssh -N -D 7070 -l user 192.168.1.51
user@192.168.1.51's password: 
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ssh -N -D 7070 -l mjfraioli 192.168.1.51
$ bg
[1]+ ssh -N -D 7070 -l user 192.168.1.51 &
```

That way you can enter the password interactively, and only once that is complete, stop it and put it into the background.

Comment: thanks for your answer , yes you right but i need a way to not stop in background , you know a way to run a process on background ?

Comment: Yes, you stop it first with CTRL-Z, then type `bg` and that will make the process continue running, but in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an ampersand to the end of your command:

```
ssh -N -D 7070 root@ip_address &
```

Explanation:

This trailing ampersand directs the shell to run the command in the background, that is, it is forked and run in a separate sub-shell, as a job, asynchronously. The shell will immediately return the return status of 0 for true and continue as normal, either processing further commands in a script or returning the cursor focus back to the user in a Linux terminal.

The shell will print out the forked process’s job number and process ID (PID) like so:

```
$ ./myscript.py &
[1] 1337
```

The stdout of the forked process will still be attached to the parent, so any output will still appear in your terminal.

After a process is forked using a single trailing ampersand &, its process ID (PID) is stored in a special variable $!. This can be used later to refer to the process:

```
$ echo $!
1337
```

Once a process is forked, it can be seen in the jobs list:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 ./myscript.py &
```

And it can be brought back to the command line before it finishes with the foreground command:

```
fg
```

The foreground command takes an optional argument of the job number, if you have forked multiple processes.

A single ampersand & can also delimit a list of commands to be run asynchronously.

```
./script.py & ./script2.py & ./script3.py &
```

In this example, all 3 python scripts are run at the same time, in separate sub-shells. Their stdout will still be attached to the parent shell, so if running this from a Linux terminal, you will still see the outputs.

This can also be used as a quick hack to take advantage of multiple cores with shell scripts, but be warned, it is a hack!

To detach a process completely from the shell, you may want to pipe the stdout and stderr to a file or to /dev/null. A nice way of doing this is with the nohup command.

*source for above explanation: http://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html*

Comment: thanks for answer , but it's not working , when i put & end of command it's goto background but it's also stop too ... how can i prevent from stop ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add option `-f` to make the ssh command run in background.
So the answer is `ssh -f -D port username@hostname -N`.